# How to convert unsigned short into unsigned char and store the value in string

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to convert unsigned short value to unsigned char type and store the result in the string. Then again converting the string back to unsigned char to get back the original unsigned short values.I got struct around this conversion.

I have converted unsigned short values to string. How do I get back unsigned short value using unsigned char array.Please help me out to solve this

```
unsigned short a=1234;
 unsigned short b=5678;
 std::string str="";
 str+=std::to_string((unsigned char)a & 0xFF);
 str+=std::to_string((unsigned char)(a>>8)& 0xFF);
 str+=std::to_string((unsigned char)b & 0xFF);
 str+=std::to_string((unsigned char)(b>>8)& 0xFF);
 cout<<"String Value: "<<str<<endl;
```

expected output to be "12345678" where a=1234 b=5678;

Comment: `auto str = std::to_string(a) + std::to_string(b)` ?

Comment: What is your actual output?

Comment: Maybe you wanted `a = 0x1234` (for mask of `0xFF`) ? else `a%100`, `(a / 100) % 100` seems more appropriate.

Comment: As @Jarod42 said, just drop the conversion to unsigned char, because first its wrong. What you're trying to code as conversion will leads to a value between [0,255], and wrapping will leads to 210 in that case. Second, its unecassery since to_string already convert any type to string. See the [online version of jarod version.](http://cpp.sh/6qz74)

Comment: perhaps you might be looking for [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you are going to get a 12 from 1,234 unless you divide by 100. Similarly, to get 56 from 5,678, you need to divide by 100. Your code doesn't divide by 100. So I can't see why you would expect a "12" or "56" in the string.

1234 decimal is 04D2 hex which ANDed with FF hex gives D2 hex or 210 decimal. Why wouldn't you expect a "210" in the string?

Again, to get 12 from 1234, you need to divide by 100. To get 34 from 1234, you need mod 100. So to get your expected output, your code needs to look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned short a=1234;
    unsigned short b=5678;
    std::string str="";
    str+=std::to_string((unsigned char)(a / 100));
    str+=std::to_string((unsigned char)(a % 100));
    str+=std::to_string((unsigned char)(b / 100));
    str+=std::to_string((unsigned char)(b % 100));
    std::cout<<"String Value: "<<str<<std::endl;
}
```

> String Value: 12345678